# Dividing two columns of pandas daraframe and keep the header name

Tags: python, pandas

With the following data frame

```
ID,WEIGHT,I1,I2,I4
1,0.2,839,1664,3266
2,0.1,851,863,858
3,0.4,1018,1999,3982
4,0.3,878,1724,3447
```

I want to iterate over I1..I4 and create new data frames by joining the `WEIGHT` column and `I_i/I1`. The following code works fine

```
for i in range(3,5):
    df_new = pd.concat([df['WEIGHT'], df.iloc[:,i]/df.iloc[:,2]], axis=1)
    print(df_new)
```

But as you can see in the output, the column header is 0 which I guess is the result of `I2/I1` and `I4/I1`.

```
   WEIGHT         0
0     0.2  1.983313
1     0.1  1.014101
2     0.4  1.963654
3     0.3  1.963554
   WEIGHT         0
0     0.2  3.892729
1     0.1  1.008226
2     0.4  3.911591
3     0.3  3.925968
```

How can I keep the columns as I2 and I4? I mean keeping the column head of `df_new` the same as `df.iloc[:,i]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is possible modify with divide by one columns `DataFrame` or by `rename`:

```
for i in range(3,5):

    df_new = df[['WEIGHT']].assign(**{df.columns[i]: df.iloc[:,i]/df.iloc[:,2]})

    df_new = pd.concat([df['WEIGHT'], df.iloc[:,[i]].div(df.iloc[:,2], axis=0)], axis=1)

    df_new = pd.concat([df['WEIGHT'],
                         df.iloc[:,i]/df.iloc[:,2].rename(df.columns[i])], axis=1)
    print(df_new)
    
   WEIGHT        I2
0     0.2  1.983313
1     0.1  1.014101
2     0.4  1.963654
3     0.3  1.963554
   WEIGHT        I4
0     0.2  3.892729
1     0.1  1.008226
2     0.4  3.911591
3     0.3  3.925968
```

---

I think no loop necessary - select columns by position and divide:

```
df.iloc[:, 3:5] = df.iloc[:, 3:5].div(df.iloc[:, 2], axis=0)
print (df)
   ID  WEIGHT    I1        I2        I4
0   1     0.2   839  1.983313  3.892729
1   2     0.1   851  1.014101  1.008226
2   3     0.4  1018  1.963654  3.911591
3   4     0.3   878  1.963554  3.925968
```

For new DataFrame:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :3], df.iloc[:, 3:5].div(df.iloc[:, 2], axis=0)], axis=1)
print (df_new)
   ID  WEIGHT    I1        I2        I4
0   1     0.2   839  1.983313  3.892729
1   2     0.1   851  1.014101  1.008226
2   3     0.4  1018  1.963654  3.911591
3   4     0.3   878  1.963554  3.925968
```

Comment: I want to further process every `df_new`. So I want to keep the loop.

Comment: @mahmood - Added 2 solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't use a loop, but rather `set_index` the non target columns, then process the data and optionally `stack` if you want a long format:

```
out = (df.set_index(['ID', 'WEIGHT'])
         .pipe(lambda d: d.div(d['I1'], axis=0))
         .stack().reset_index(name='value')
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your new dataframe in a loop, you could assign a new column to `df[['WEIGHT'][]` and then rename that column appropriately:

```py
cols = df.columns.to_list()
for i in range(3, 5):
    col = cols[i]
    df_new = df_new = df[['WEIGHT']].assign(**{col: df[col]/df.iloc[:, 2]})
    print(df_new)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   WEIGHT        I2
0     0.2  1.983313
1     0.1  1.014101
2     0.4  1.963654
3     0.3  1.963554
   WEIGHT        I4
0     0.2  3.892729
1     0.1  1.008226
2     0.4  3.911591
3     0.3  3.925968
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to rename, you can assign with `n = cols[i] ; df_new = df[['WEIGHT']].assign(**{n: df[n]/df.iloc[:, 2]})`

Comment: @mozway ah yes - I forget that you can use a dict there. Answer edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the column headers in the new data frames by setting them to the corresponding column name from the original data frame. You can use the `rename` method to achieve this.

Here's how you can modify your code to keep the column headers as I2 and I4:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'WEIGHT': [0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3],
    'I1': [839, 851, 1018, 878],
    'I2': [1664, 863, 1999, 1724],
    'I4': [3266, 858, 3982, 3447]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(3, 5):
    column_name = df.columns[i]
    df_new = pd.concat([df['WEIGHT'], df.iloc[:, i] / df['I1']], axis=1)
    # To be added on your code
    df_new = df_new.rename(columns={'WEIGHT': 'WEIGHT', 0: column_name})
    print(df_new)
```

**Output:**

```
    WEIGHT    I2
0     0.2  1.983313
1     0.1  1.014101
2     0.4  1.963654
3     0.3  1.963554
    WEIGHT    I4
0     0.2  3.892729
1     0.1  1.008226
2     0.4  3.911591
3     0.3  3.925968
```

Comment: This answer (and others of yours) looks AI-generated, as a reminder, [this is strictly forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: It is not AI-generated. I have added only one line to the existing code to get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

Indexing with [[column name]] does not remove column name.(becuz it is dataframe not series) And `join` is more convenient than `concat` for horizontal concatenation

```
for i in df.columns[3:]:
    df_new = df[['WEIGHT']].join(df[[i]].div(df['I1'], axis=0))
    print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which uses `numpy` for vectorized division of columns:

```
df[['I2', 'I4']] = df.iloc[:, -2:].values / df['I1'].values.reshape(-1,1)
[df[['WEIGHT', x]] for x in ['I2', 'I4']]
```

Output:

```
 [   WEIGHT        I2
 0     0.2  1.983313
 1     0.1  1.014101
 2     0.4  1.963654
 3     0.3  1.963554,
    WEIGHT        I4
 0     0.2  3.892729
 1     0.1  1.008226
 2     0.4  3.911591
 3     0.3  3.925968]
```